# vb.net Property access must assign to the property or use its value in windows forms

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

i am working in vb.net windows application

in my load event i am giving code like this for loading data from different table to my datagridview.

for that i given code like this:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select M.Model,c.Colname,ma.Make from Model_tbl M join Color_tbl C on c.colid=M.mdlid join Make_tbl ma on ma.mkid=c.colid  where mdlid=5", con.connect)
        Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables("MyTable")

        End If
```

When clicking update button I want to update data to different tables from my datagridview.. so I wrote code like this in my update button event..

```
 Me.Validate()
            da.UpdateCommand(ds.Tables("MyTable"))
            Me.ds.AcceptChanges()
```

but i am getting error in this line:

```
da.UpdateCommand(ds.Tables("MyTable"))
```

Error:

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Answer (score 1):

don't you think instead of

```
da.UpdateCommand(ds.Tables("MyTable"))
```

you should be doing

```
da.Update(ds.Tables("MyTable"))
```

da.UpdateCommand is a property not a method , you use it to `set the update command`, just as you have used the `select command`

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select M.Model,c.Colname,ma.Make from Model_tbl M join Color_tbl C on c.colid=M.mdlid join Make_tbl ma on ma.mkid=c.colid  where mdlid=5", con.connect)
        Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
```

also note that

> The SelectCommand property must be set before you call the Fill
>   method of the DataAdapter. The InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, or
>   DeleteCommand properties must be set before the Update method of the
>   DataAdapter is called, depending on what changes were made to the data
>   in the DataTable. For example, if rows have been added, the
>   InsertCommand must be set before you call Update. When Update is
>   processing an inserted, updated, or deleted row, the DataAdapter uses
>   the respective Command property to process the action.
>
> If Update is called and the appropriate command does not exist for a
>   particular update (for example, no DeleteCommand for deleted rows), an
>   exception is thrown.

also note that you can only use [CommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate commands for single table, not joined tables like you have. you would have to explicitly set the update command.

Comment: if i am giving like this getting error:Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

Comment: it means you need to explicitly set the updatecommand(or insertcommand,deleteCommand, see edit) property, because it cannot generate the required sql for updation dynamically. see this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a8f3565-ca1d-4042-b18d-e46cc8e26e3f/dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables